# Typecasting overloading of a forward defined class

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, c++17, c++14

I have this simple program which converts Cartesian coordinates to Polar coordinates. I want to convert vice-versa as well. So I tried to use typecasting operator with the Cartesian class by forward-declaring it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

class Cartesian;

class Polar{
   double dist,angle;
   public:
   Polar(double a,double b): dist(a),angle(b){}
   Polar(){ dist=0; angle=0; }  //In case no parameters provided, this default constructor will be called
   operator Cartesian(){
      double x=dist*cos((angle/180)*M_PI);
      double y=dist*sin((angle/180)*M_PI);
      return Cartesian(x,y);
   }
   friend double getDATA(Polar,int);
};

double getDATA(Polar a,int opt=1){
   if(opt==1) return a.dist;
   else return a.angle;
}

class Cartesian{
   double x,y;
   public: Cartesian(){ x=0; y=0; }
   Cartesian(double a,double b): x(a),y(b){}
   operator Polar(){   //NOTICE:- No return type is mentioned
     double distance= sqrt(x*x+y*y);
     double angle= atan(y/x);
     angle=(angle*180)/M_PI;
     return Polar(distance,angle);  //Note that new keyword is used to return pointers (allocate memory in the heap), don't use it here
   }
};

int main(){
  double x,y;
  cout<<"Enter the X and Y coordinates= "; cin>>x>>y;
  Cartesian c(x,y);
  Polar p=c;
  cout<<"Distance= "<<getDATA(p)<<endl;
  cout<<"Gradient= "<<getDATA(p,3)<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

But on compiling, it gives me these 2 errors:

1. return type "class Cartesian" is incomplete
2. invalid use of incomplete type "class Cartesian"

Is there a workaround for this? I really want these 2 classes to be able to convert from one another.

Comment: *"Is forward declaration of classes not supported in C++?"* -- this seems to be quite the logical leap, given that you were told that you had an invalid use of an incomplete type (implying that there are valid uses, hence there is support).

Comment: Does this answer the question you actually asked (*"Is forward declaration of classes not supported in C++?"*)? [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration) (Did you maybe instead want to ask if/how to make your intended setup work?)

Comment: I would take a different approach - get rid of the conversion operators entirely, and use [converting constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) instead. Then the inputs can be reference types, which can be forward-declared. `class Cartesian; class Polar; class Polar{ ... public: ... Polar(const Cartesian&); ... }; class Cartesian{ ... public: ... Cartesian(const Polar&); ... };` This will still allow you to use a `Cartesian` object wherever a `Polar` object is expected, and vice versa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of "[error: member access into incomplete type : forward declaration of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19962859/90527)", "[Forward declaration doesn't work with conversion operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7272622/90527)".

Answer (score 1):

> Is forward declaration of classes not supported in C++?

Yes, forward declaration of classes is supported in C++.

However, you cannot define a function with incomplete return type. You must define the return type before defining the function.

> Now I see. But is there a workaround for this

Yes. Define the return types before defining the functions.

Comment: Now I see. But is there a workaround for this? Because I want both of these classes to be able to convert from each other

Comment: @SaptarshiDey Yes, just define `Polar::operator Cartesian()` after `class Cartesian` is defined.